# TestNG Assert.assertEquals fails when one of the variable is null

Tags: java, testng, assertions

```
String test = null;
Assert.assertEquals(test, "test", "Null test passed");
```

I expect the above assertion to fail since "null" and "test" are not equal. However, assertion passes silently although it doesn't continue with test execution. Can someone explain it to me please?

Comment: My guess is that an exception is being thrown, particularly if `equals()` is being called on a `null` value for `test`.

Comment: How are you running this? Do you have [assertions enabled](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/assert.html#enable-disable)?

Comment: It will not pass, and it will show the following message: `org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<[test]> but was:<[Null test passed]>`. Are you sure you simply don't have your message wrong and you want to say _Null test failed_?

Comment: I got the problem. I was running a data-driven test and realized that assertions don't exit the test and report the error intermediately but instead continue to run the tests until all inputs from DataProvider are complete and outputs the result finally.